# Struggling with buttons

Tags: button, arduino

Ive been really struggling recently with one problem.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to make one button trigger one sequence on an 8x8 display for 10 seconds and go off AND also have another button to make a different sequence for 10 seconds then go off and so on.

If anyone can help me please respond, it would be much appreciated :)

MATTY :))))

Answer (score 0):

Very poorly described problem, please include your code or the way you try to solve this problem - this will make it much easier to answer your problem.

But assuming that you want to click one of the buttons and disable all buttons for the next 10 seconds, you can use `millis()`. [Learn more about millis()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/)

Here's an example:

```
unsigned long millisec = 0;
```

In void loop include this, it will not execute the code within 10 seconds of the last accepted press:

```
if (button1 == true && millis() > millisec + 10000) {
  // Button 1 code:


  millisec = millis();
} else if (button2 == true && millis() > millisec + 10000) {
  // Button 2 code:


  millisec = millis();
}
```

Comment: Sorry :(                                      Here is the description used by my tutor but i dont quite understand the setup: